# Unable to nest categories in menu

Tags: menus

I have an issue with the new custom menu in WP3. Suddenly the nesting of categories stopped working and even though it's possible to nest them in the UI, when I press Save, then they all go back flat. Any chance someone has experienced this and know a way to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, **try disabling all of your plugins**. If that fixes it, re-enable them one by one until you find the culprit.